# How to use neo4j in JSP

Tags: java, database, servlets, web-applications, neo4j

I'm making a Thesaurus on Java and my database I'm using is neo4j. Now I want to build this Thesaurus as a web application, this is a simple web app like JSP + servlet. What can I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of the [published java drivers](http://www.neo4j.org/develop/drivers) to talk to the neo4j server. I recommend using Spring Data to avoid writing the scaffolding code yourselves. Read this small book to get started: [Good Relationships](http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/good-relationships-spring-data)

Comment: How about REST API and JSP?